# Fullcalendar business hour don't care about DOW

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar 3.0.1](https://fullcalendar.io/download/) and I'm trying to implement the business hours as the [example page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/) shows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullcalendar(
        // [...]
        businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
            {
                dow: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
                start: '08:00', // 8am
                end: '18:00' // 6pm
            },
            {
                dow: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
                start: '10:00', // 10am
                end: '16:00' // 4pm
            }
         ]
    );
});
```

But Fullcalendar doesn't care about the `dow` attribute. The bussiness hours are rendered but only the `start` and `end` attributes are considered.

Any suggestion on how to fix this problem? It's a fullcalendar bug or just me?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: That's the example... I've done nothing else the load a few static events and the business hours... Just to try

Comment: The example is just documentation and code - nothing to base it off of. How do you know what the calendar should look like?

Comment: You can put your sample code on jsfiddle in order to reproduce your issue?

Comment: The problem was in the css file... I've created a js fiddle with the same code I've posted and it worked fine... my fault... should I remove the question?